# In Yii2 QueryBuilder, what is the syntax for using a database component not named 'db'?

Tags: php, yii2, query-builder

In a Yii2 project I need to use QueryBuilder with 2 db components named 'dbcore' and 'dbdata'. I have been searching for how to do this and have only found the following (but no example):

"All these query methods take an optional $db parameter representing the DB connection that should be used to perform a DB query. If you omit this parameter, the db application component will be used as the DB connection." 
(https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder)

For example, consider this demo case:

```
$count = (new Query())->from('user')->count();
```

I have tried Query('dbcore') and Query(['db'=>'dbcore']) and Query([$db=>'dbcore']) without success, but I am groping in the dark. Could someone please advise what the correct syntax is?

NOTE: I did try this workround in the component array and the query works fine, but it is not ideal in my application:

```
'db'     => require(__DIR__.'/dbcore.php'),     // 'db' is expected default in Query()
'dbcore' => require(__DIR__.'/dbcore.php'),
'dbdata' => require(__DIR__.'/dbdata.php'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Query method" in your case is [`count()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#count()-detail):

```
$count = (new Query())->from('user')->count('*', Yii::$app->dbcore);
```

Comment: (My first time so not sure if I can use a comment to express thanks). Thank you very much for explaining that. I now see it clearly specified in the public method definitions of Yii\db\Query - I would never have guessed to look there!